# pip install nose==1.3.7 installs version 0.10.4

Tags: python, pip, nose

I'm trying to force pip to install nose v1.3.7. Using the following command:

```
pip install --proxy **** --no-cache -I nose==1.3.7
```

but, I get the following output:

[image]

Why is pip installing 0.10.4 instead, after I specifically asked for 1.3.7?

I should note that I'm doing is within a python virtualenv.

Other details: Centos 6.8, python 2.6, pip 8.1.2

Comment: Did you check the version of the installed module? (maybe just that print out has a problem?)

Comment: I've also tried doing a pip download and installing from that- same problem.

Comment: Is nose 0.10.4 already installed in the virtualenv?  If so, try deleting the virtualenv and recreating it with nose 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing an uninstall of nose and reinstalling it seems to have worked. Still uncertain why the -I flag didn't do as it's intended to do.